# Not using predicate in condition variable causing slowdown

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, predicate, condition-variable

I am trying to build a camera wrapper that allows other threads to retrieve a frame, while the wrapper handles all the processing in a separate thread.
The main purpose of using a condition variable to notify other threads of a new frame being ready is so that other threads do not get the same frame twice. In a way, this is a case of the producer-consumer problem.

During initialization, I initialize a thread to do to the capture and processing:

```
int PiCamera::Init(){
    camera_on_ = true;
    capture_thread_ = std::thread(&PiCamera::RetrieveFrames, this);
    return 0;
}
```

where RetrieveFrames is:

```
int PiCamera::RetrieveFrames1(){
while(camera_on_){
    camera_.grab();
    frame_ready_ = true;
    ready_condition_.notify_all(); // Notify on condition variable
}
return 0;
}
```

Now when there is a single thread trying to get a frame, all the thread needs to call is:

```
int PiCamera::GetFrame1(cv::Mat &image){
    // Lock mutex
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mutex_lock(ready_mutex_);
    ready_condition_.wait(mutex_lock, [this](){return frame_ready_;});
    camera_.retrieve(image);
    frame_ready_ = false;
    // Unlock mutex
    mutex_lock.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if two threads call the function GetFrame, each one of them will only be able to get alernate frames. However, I want any number of incoming threads to be able to get the latest frame as soon as it is available.

Here, it seems like this is like a producer-consumer problem with multiple consumers, but all the consumers should be able to get the latest data available, and should not read the same data twice.

Hence, I made the following changes:

```
int PiCamera::RetrieveFrames2(){
    while(camera_on_){
        camera_.grab();
        // frame_ready_ = true;
        ready_condition_.notify_all(); // Notify on condition variable
    }
    return 0;
}

int PiCamera::GetFrame2(cv::Mat &image){
    // Lock mutex
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mutex_lock(ready_mutex_);
    // ready_condition_.wait(mutex_lock, [this](){return frame_ready_;});
    ready_condition_.wait(mutex_lock);
    camera_.retrieve(image);
    // frame_ready_ = false;
    // Unlock mutex
    mutex_lock.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I could use 2 threads to get the same frame, but I noticed some slowdowns in retrieving frames.

The program I ran was kinda like this:

```
PiCamera camera();
camera.Init();
cv::Point2f centroid_location;
cv::Mat image;
float time1[NFRAMES] = {};
float time2[NFRAMES] = {};
float time3[NFRAMES] = {};
timeval tstart, tend, t1, t2, t3;

for(int frame=0;frame<NFRAMES;frame++){
    gettimeofday(&t1, nullptr);
    camera->GetFrame(image);
    gettimeofday(&t2, nullptr);
    time1[frame] = ElapsedSec(t1, t2)*1000;
    GetCentroid(image, centroid_location);
    // Just to increase workload
    GetCentroid(image, centroid_location);
    gettimeofday(&t3, nullptr);
    time2[frame] = ElapsedSec(t2, t3)*1000;
}

gettimeofday(&tend, nullptr);
float total_time = ElapsedSec(tstart, tend);
float fps = (float)NFRAMES/total_time;
std::cout << "Camera took " << total_time << " seconds at " << fps << " FPS\n";
std::cout << "t1 " << ArrayMean(time1, NFRAMES) << " t2 " << ArrayMean(time2, NFRAMES) << '\n';
```

The camera is able to grab at a framerate of 120FPS, So I was hoping I would be able to process the frames at 120FPS as well.

When I run the program using *RetrieveFrames1* and *GetFrames1*, I get this:

```
Camera took 8.39579 seconds at 119.107 FPS
t1 0.367703 t2 8.02553
```

However, when I do this test using *RetrieveFrames2* and *GetFrames2*:

```
Camera took 13.7088 seconds at 72.946 FPS
t1 4.74955 t2 8.95662
```

Even if i call *GetCentroid* Just once, I get the following results:

```
Camera took 8.29365 seconds at 120.574 FPS
t1 3.98624 t2 4.30591
```

and

```
Camera took 8.94322 seconds at 111.817 FPS
t1 4.43984 t2 4.50159
```

Why are my threads taking so much longer to wait on the condition variable here when only thing I have done is to remove the predicate?

Comment: I'd say you have a much worse problem, as you use `notify_all` which wakes *all* threads waiting on the condition variable. If you have many threads doing that you will have a rush and all will attempt to get the image. Instead use `notify_one` which should wake up a single "random" thread that will get the image.

Comment: I don't have time to read all that code, but your `bool frame_ready` variable sounds suspicious to me.  My immediate thought was, I probably would have an `int` variable that says _which_ frame is ready (e.g., `newest_ready_frame_number`.)

Comment: Hey @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for responding!
I was wondering if the threads are only copying the image data, would the all of them rushing at the same time still be a problem? there is no race condition on the image data itself!

Comment: @jameslarge That seems like a good solution actually! Right now, when I use `frame_ready`, The calling thread does not need to maintain any state, since it knows that if the earlier frame has not been taken, the value will be true, and false otherwise. If I do make it numbered, then the calling thread will somehow need to keep track of the last frame number it tried to retrieve. Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of waiting for `frame_ready` to become `true`, each thread waits for `newest_ready_frame_number` to become different from the last frame number that the thread previously knew about.

Comment: thanks @jameslarge! I was also thinking if I could maintain a map of <thread id><frame_ready> each thread could maintain its own state as well. Would that be less efficient in any way than just maintaining a frame number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, I ended up using https://github.com/rigtorp/MPMCQueue to abstract away the logic of transferring the data between the consumer and producer threads

Answer (score 0):

```
int PiCamera::RetrieveFrames1(){
while(camera_on_){
    camera_.grab();
    frame_ready_ = true;
    ready_condition_.notify_all(); // Notify on condition variable
}
```

This is broken because this thread modified `frame_ready_` without holding the mutex that protects it.

```
int PiCamera::RetrieveFrames2(){
    while(camera_on_){
        camera_.grab();
        // frame_ready_ = true;
        ready_condition_.notify_all(); // Notify on condition variable
    }
    return 0;
```

This is broken because it calls `notify_all` without changing any shared state protected by the mutex. You must change the shared state while holding the mutex either before calling `notify_all` or after calling `notify_all` but before releasing the mutex.

```
int PiCamera::GetFrame2(cv::Mat &image){
    // Lock mutex
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mutex_lock(ready_mutex_);
    // ready_condition_.wait(mutex_lock, [this](){return frame_ready_;});
    ready_condition_.wait(mutex_lock);
    camera_.retrieve(image);
    // frame_ready_ = false;
    // Unlock mutex
    mutex_lock.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

This is broken because it calls `wait` without first checking that the shared state protected by the mutex is in a state other than the one that it is waiting for. You can't wait for something that has already happened. You *must* check the shrared state before calling `wait`.

Condition variables work well if, and only if, they are used in conjunction with shared state protected by a mutex. Threads that call notify functions must change the shared state under the mutex's protection. Threads that wait must check the shared state under the mutex's protection to determine whether they need to wait at all and then whether they're done waiting.

While it is possible to break these rules and still have your code work, it takes deep knowledge and expertise to use condition variables reliably otherwise.

> Why are my threads taking so much longer to wait on the condition variable here when only thing I have done is to remove the predicate?

Because nothing prevents the thread from waiting for something that has already happened.